# Open another fragment by clicking

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I Already have a Navigation bar that changes fragments for me without any problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mobile_navigation"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    app:startDestination="@+id/navigation_home">


    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/navigation_tools"
        android:name="com.example.gsm.ui.tools.toolsFragment"
        android:label="@string/title_Tools"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
 
</navigation>
```

This is my Activity_Main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="0dp">

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="@color/background" 
        app:itemIconSize="27dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/red"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/red"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_activity_main"
        android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:defaultNavHost="true"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/nav_view"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

My navigation bar swaps fragments easily for me, but I want to disable the navigation bar and I need some buttons to do exactly what the navigation bar used to do for me.

I'm new to Android/XML , and the transaction between fragments in the Internet was not synced with my files and codes and If I add content to a frame layout All my designs will mess up.

Comment: I recommend use new Google technology NavigationUI
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui
Is simple, auto and have many examples. 
Like this looking another fragment opening

`Navigation.findNavController(binding.root).navigate(FirstFragmentDirection.actionNavigateToSecondFragment())`

Answer (score 0):

In this case [FragmentContainerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentContainerView) and FragmentManager ,[Fragment transactions](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/transactions#java) help us .

> FragmentContainerView is a customized Layout designed specifically for Fragments. It extends FrameLayout, so it can reliably handle Fragment Transactions, and it also has additional features to coordinate with fragment behavior.
>
> At runtime, a FragmentManager can add, remove, replace, and perform other actions with fragments in response to user interaction.

So you can take a `FragmentContainerView` in your activity_main.xml where you can add different fragment by button/user action.

So your activity_main.xml looks like now -

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Test button"></Button>

    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button">
    </androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Now Create a new Blank Fragment to your project to test . IDE automatically override some methods and layout for your fragment also for this .

[image]

So your `BlankFragment.class` looks like -

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;

import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 * Use the {@link BlankFragment#newInstance} factory method to
 * create an instance of this fragment.
 */
public class BlankFragment extends Fragment {

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    public BlankFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment BlankFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static BlankFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        BlankFragment fragment = new BlankFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
    }
}
```

Now From your Activity you can show the Blank Fragment in `FragmentContainerView` , we define its id `fragment_container_view` in activity_main.xml .

Here Your `MainActivity.class` -

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainBinding binding;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    button = findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_view, BlankFragment.class, null);
            transaction.commit();

        }
    });


}

  }
```

All of these just for example . You should check documentation to know more .